# How to get variable name?

Tags: variables, unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
var testint=1;

var teststr="val";

var val1=5;//print value

var val2=8;

var val3=4;

Debug.Log(this[teststr+testint.ToString()]);
```

//I want to variable name value.

Comment: What is "variable name value"?

Comment: I want to print val1 is my example.

Comment: you are alooking for a variables variable .. dub http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript

Comment: but I want to variable name.according to testint number;

Answer (score 0):

If

```
var testint = 1;
var teststr = "val";
var val1 = 5;
var val2 = 8;
var val3 = 4;
```

then

```
window[teststr + testint.toString()]
```

will output `5` (the value of variable `val1`).

Similarly, if

```
var testint = 2;
var teststr = "val";
var val1 = 5;
var val2 = 8;
var val3 = 4;
```

the outputed value will be `8` (value of variable `val2`).

Comment: I want to Unity javascript.